# How do I grab users' email addresses for a specific job Title attribute?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, filtering, user-accounts

I am trying to run a script to obtain a specific Job title along with their name and email address and export to CSV. The Job title I am looking for is `"CW -OTHER"`.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Some steering in the right direction will be appreciated.

```bsh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title  | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title "CW - OTHER" | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email_Addresses.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform that filtering with the `Select-Object` cmdlet...

```bsh
| select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title "CW - OTHER"
```

...which won't work.  Use the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) for that...

```bsh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq 'CW - OTHER' } `
    | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email_Addresses.csv"
```

Note that you could also use the `-Filter` or `-LdapFilter` parameters of [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser) to specify a filter to be executed server-side, which would be more efficient.  Something like...

```bsh
Get-ADUser -Filter { Title -eq 'CW - OTHER' } -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title `
    | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email_Addresses.csv"
```

Comment: @Bacon I don't know if it's a choice or if you didn't knew but you can use the pipe `|` to end your line and continue to the next line without having to use backticks everywhere.

Comment: Even better, I'm just told that you can use pipe `|` at the beginning of the line too but only starting from PS core. My previous comment still stand though.

Comment: @SagePourpre I am aware, yes.  I prefer to use leading pipes.  I did not know that about Core, though.